# Randomly select from a set of questions

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to recreate the game of hacks because there isn't an API to create my own questions, and implement on external site , however I am using django with restful framework for this task. (I am not sure , if this is the right to achieve this). I will do this via server because I dont want people to change js and bypass the stuff or even disable js and stop time , and continue with the same question, but how can I translate into django this?

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

from .models import Question, Choice
from .serializers import QuestionListPageSerializer, QuestionDetailPageSerializer, ChoiceSerializer, VoteSerializer, QuestionResultPageSerializer


@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def questions_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        questions = Question.objects.all()
        serializer = QuestionListPageSerializer(questions, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = QuestionListPageSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            question = serializer.save()
            return Response(QuestionListPageSerializer(question).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

```
class QuestionListPageSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    question_text = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = serializers.DateTimeField()
    was_published_recently = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True) # Serializer is smart enough to understand that was_published_recently is a method on Question
    code = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Question.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        for key, value in validated_data.items():
            setattr(instance, key, value)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

python test case

```
import random
import pprint
def pick_ten(fname):
    question_list = []
    for question in open(fname):
        # strip off new line character
        question = question.rstrip()
        question_list.append(question)
    return random.sample(question_list, 1)
# testing ...
filename = "Questions101.txt"
question_list = pick_ten(filename)
pprint.pprint(question_list)
```

response test case

```
xxxxxx@xxxxxx:~$ python3 quiz.py 
['What was the first brand name for Bubble Gum?']
xxxxxx@xxxxxx:~$ python3 quiz.py 
['Which game uses the phrase "en passant"?']
xxxxxx@xxxxxx:~$ python3 quiz.py 
['What type of organism causes malaria?']
xxxxxx@xxxxxx:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this using [**`order_by('?')`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#order-by):

```
# random_questions.py

from quizapp.models import Question

def pick_random():
    return Question.objects.all().order_by('?').first()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    question = pick_random()
    print(question.question_text)

# run

python manage.py shell < /path/to/random_questions.py
```